# 'System.ServiceModel.OperationContext' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments error

Tags: c#, constructor

In My windows form

```
  private OperationContext op = new OperationContext();
```

and its gives no error, but

in another project i add this line of code (Same machine,same .NET version ) it gives

> 'System.ServiceModel.OperationContext' does not contain a constructor
>   that takes '0' arguments

error can any one help me ??

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but in your Winforms project.. is OperationContext really the one from System.ServiceModel? Because the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) says there is only one constructor and it needs an argument of type `IContextChannel`. Go to the definition of the OperationContext in the WinForm and see where that leads as if it really is from System.ServiceModel, then I am surprised it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an argument that inherits from `IContextChannel`.  The `OperationContext` class has no constructor that takes 0 arguments as an overload.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.operationcontext.aspx

Comment: `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext` is in the base class library.. he cannot edit that and thus cannot add a constructor for it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Then maybe there are different OperationContext classes? The one you fully qualified has only one [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.operationcontext%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which does indeed take a parameter.